# how to implement factory design pattern in node js

Tags: javascript, node.js, factory

I have a app.js file as below.
I am getting an error DesignFactory is not defined,

```
var fs = require('fs');
var dotenv = require('dotenv');
dotenv.load();
var designtokenfile = require ('./designtokenfile');
var designtokendb = require ('./designtokendb');

DesignFactory.storeDesign = function(type) {
if (type == 'file') {
  return designtokenfile;
}
else if (type == 'db') 
{
return designtokendb;
 }
};
module.exports.DesignFactory = DesignFactory;
```

Since am new to nodejs environment I dont know how to write it. Please help me

Answer (score 0):

you should declare the `DesignFactory` as a object before define property `storeDesign`.

file1.js

```
var fs = require('fs');
var dotenv = require('dotenv');
dotenv.load();
var designtokenfile = require ('./designtokenfile');
var designtokendb = require ('./designtokendb');

// declare the DesignFactory variable as a plain object.
var DesignFactory = {};

DesignFactory.storeDesign = function(type) {
  if (type == 'file') {
    return designtokenfile;
  } else if (type == 'db') {
    return designtokendb;
  }
};
module.exports.DesignFactory = DesignFactory;
```

usage in file2.js

```
var DesignFactory = require('./file1');
DesignFactory.storeDesign(/*arguments*/);
```

**Note**: 
Like the David Barker's answer, if you mean the DesignFactory is like a class in JAVA, you should define it as a Function.

```
function DesignFactory() {};
```

Comment: Thank you for your response. If I need to call storeDesign in other nodejs file how can I call it. Please help with code to call storeDesign method.

Answer (score 0):

From what I see you don't declare `DesignFactory` at any point. Start by declaring it's constructor.

```
// Constructor ES5
var DesignFactory = function() { ... }

// Prototype methods (must instantiate class to use these)
DesignFactory.prototype = {
    storeDesign: function(type) {
        // Code here
    }
}

// Or you can use the static approach as in your code
DesignFactory.storeDesign = function(type) { ... }
```

Alternatively, you can use a standard object.

```
var DesignFactory = {};

DesignFactory.storeDesign = function(type) {
    // Code here
};
```